# Wrong path for theme assets

Tags: theme-development, paths

I'm working on a WordPress project, starting from Mark Jaquith's [WordPress-Skeleton](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton) repository, using MAMP.

I cloned the repo, updated the WordPress submodule, created a database and updated the `local-config.php` file.

Everything seems to be fine so far, but when I try to use a different theme (placing it on `/content/themes`), all the theme's assets get the wrong path (so the site is rendered with no images, no CSS and no JS). For example:

In the source code, a stylesheet link points to:

`http://localhost/content/themes/roots/assets/css/main.min.css`

when it should be:

`http://localhost/lab/Wordpress-Skeleton/content/themes/roots/assets/css/main.min.css`

I'm getting the wrong path for all assets in my themes (any theme I place into `/content/themes`)

For example, in the source code, a stylesheet link points to:

`http://localhost/content/themes/roots/assets/css/main.min.css`

when it should be:

`http://localhost/lab/Wordpress-Skeleton/content/themes/roots/assets/css/main.min.css`

While debugging I found out that the global $wp_theme_directories returns an array with two paths, and both are correct:

`.../htdocs/lab/WordPress-Skeleton/wp/wp-content/themes
.../htdocs/lab/WordPress-Skeleton/content/themes`

but, the function `get_theme_root_uri()` when called from the `functions.php` of a theme located on the second path from the `$wp_theme_directories` array, returns:

`http://localhost/content/themes`

The themes from the folder `/wp/wp-content/themes` (the default ones that came with the WP submodule update) work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the problem was with `WP_CONTENT_URL`, defined inside wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/lab/WordPress-Skeleton/content' );
```

It seems that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is returning an incomplete path (only `localhost` without the folder).

Since I'm using version control and using a local-config.php to define some local dev variables (like database credentials), I also placed this on it:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/lab/WordPress-Skeleton/content' );
```

and on wp-config.php I added this check:

```
if ( !defined( 'WP_CONTENT_URL' ) )
    define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/content' );
```

Comment: Can you explain why that made the difference? Other people with the same problem would be helped by a better description of the solution.